# Is it safe to use void** in special cases? Still undefined behavior?

Tags: c, malloc

I want to create a function that frees the memory pointed to by the pointer and assigns this pointer to NULL. So I have to declare the argument as `void**` (an indirect pointer), I know that `void*` is safe for converting pointers, and using `void**` is undefined behavior. But I think that should be no problem in this situation.Will this function safely free any memory allocated by `malloc()` without undefined behavior?  Ask the hackers to help or suggest a better way.

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// If I use safeFree(&mac_arr); ,
// it will warn "Incompatible pointer types passing ' int **' to parameter of type ' void **'"
// So I used #define, don't care about this.

#define SAFE_FREE(p) safeFree((void **)&(p))

void safeFree(void ** ptr);

int main(void) {
    int *mac_arr = malloc(sizeof *mac_arr);
    SAFE_FREE(mac_arr);
    return 0;
}

void safeFree(void ** ptr){
    if (ptr != NULL && *ptr != NULL) {
        free(*ptr);
        *ptr = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe cast it to a `void *` and then to a `void **`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer types `int **` and `void **` are incompatible. The type cast just masks the incompatibility.

You could define:

```
#define SAFE_FREE(p) ((void)(free(p), (p) = NULL))
```

Comment: @lan Abbott I don't know what the purpose of (void) is, please specify, and can I write this? `#define SAFE_FREE(p) free(p);(p) = NULL`

Comment: The cast to `void` is merely to thwart any attempts to assign the value of `SAFE_FREE(p)` to a variable. The problem with `#define SAFE_FREE(p) free(p); (p) = NULL` is that it is two statements (when terminated by a semi-colon), so `if (foo) SAFE_FREE(bar);` wouldn't work (the `(bar) = NULL;` part would always be done). A common workaround is `#define SAFE_FREE(p) do { free(p); (p) = NULL; } while (0)`, which is a single, compound statement when terminated by a semi-colon.

Comment: A significant difference between the "expression" form of the macro such as `#define SAFE_FREE(p) (free(p), (p) = NULL)` (I left out the `(void)` cast for you) and the "statement" form of the macro such as `#define SAFE_FREE(p) do { free(p); (p) = NULL; } while (0)` is that the "expression" form can be used within another expression (especially a comma expression), whereas the "statement" form cannot. (An expression can form a statement, but a statement cannot form an expression - at least not in standard C.)

Comment: @lan Abbott Thank you, I understand.~

Comment: @Treasone Also, be aware that calls such as `SAFE_FREE(*foo++)` will not work with any of these macros because `*foo++` is evaluated twice by the macro.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior of such code is not defined by the C standard.

In `main`, `mac_arr` is an `int *`. The parameter `safeFree` receives is a pointer to `void *`. But `int *` and `void *` are not compatible types as defined by the C standard. They may have different sizes, alignment requirements, and representations. So converting the address of `mac_arr` from `int **` to `void **` and using `*ptr` for an lvalue of type `void *` is not portable.

It might “work” in many C implementations.

The `SAFE_FREE` macro you are contemplating is not a great remedy for pointer problems. While it sets the current pointer to an object to null, it has no way of affecting other pointers to the same object, such as links in linked lists or links in other data structures.

(It also does not need to test `*ptr != NULL`. `free` is specified to do nothing when it is passed a null pointer, so you would just be doubling up on a test that is already performed.)